# wait in the main thread for an AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

in my app I need to perform a network operations so I made an `AsyncTask` class to perform it on background but then I need to fill some textview with the information that I got.

So my question is what can I do in the main thread to wait for the `AsyncTask` class to finish the `doInBackground` operations

**This is my AsyncTask class:**

```
public class ObtenerDatos extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private PuertosSaxParser saxparser;
    private ArrayList<clsPuertos> Puertos;

    /** Return the Puertos info to the main class */
    public ArrayList<clsPuertos> getPuertos() {
        return Puertos;
    }

    /** Get the XML info and do the parse */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            saxparser = new PuertosSaxParser("http://www.androide.comyr.com/valores.xml");
            Puertos = saxparser.parseXML();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**And this is how I call it from the main thread:**

```
try {
    int_datos.execute();
    //HERE I NEED TO WAIT FOR THE AsyncTask TO COMPLETE THE doInBackground OPERATIONS
    Puertos = int_datos.getPuertos();
    //THEN I FILL THE TEXTVIEWs WITH THE INFO OF Puertos
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

**MainClass:**

```
ObtenerDatos int_datos = new ObtenerDatos(this);
int_datos.execute();
```

**ObtenerDatos (AsyncTask class):**

```
public class ObtenerDatos extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private PuertosSaxParser saxparser;
    private ArrayList<clsPuertos> Puertos;
    private Context contexto;
    final TextView textSanferPleamarHora = new TextView(contexto);

    public ObtenerDatos(Context contexto){
        this.contexto = contexto;
    }
```

I try to pass the context from the Main to the `AsyncTask` class to set up the `TextViews` there but I get some errors.

Is this right?

Comment: set text or update ui in onPostExecute() or use runonuithread un doinbackgroundd() to update ui

Comment: You can also use callbacks like I do here: https://github.com/nedwidek/Android-Rest-API. The basic point is that you do not wait. You allow the UI thread to continue so that the system stays responsive and pick up execution when the server returns data.

Answer (score 3):

> So my question is what can I do in the main thread to wait for the AsyncTask class to finish the "doInBackground" operations

Do not do this. The **complete and entire point** of using something like `AsyncTask` is to **not** block the main application thread.

Please "fill some textview with the information that I got" in `onPostExecute()` of the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do it like you say but I need to get the "context" from the MainClass to the AsyncTask class to set up the TextViews but I have a problem with it, i have errors giving the context from main to the other class.

I put a new example in my question

Is this right? Thanks again

Comment: @Fox: "Is this right?" -- probably not. Usually you do not create a `TextView` from Java code this way. The best way presently to manage an `AsyncTask` is to have it be held by a retained `Fragment`. The `AsyncTask` can then use the `Fragment` in `onPostExecute()` (or `onProgressUpdate()`) to get at necessary widgets for updating the results.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever data u want to set to textView you just can simply do it in the postExecute method u can share your data from doInbackground just put the last void as string and just pass the string